# Handle Potentailly dangerous request-MVC-ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I handle potentially dangerous request in MVc?

I am using the following in the global.asax to handle the error, but its not catching those errors.

Its catching other error types.`

```
           else if (httpException is HttpRequestValidationException)
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "General");

            }`
```

any one done this in MVc?

Answer (score 2):

In mvc, in general [HandleErrorAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) is used to handle exceptions and return specific view based on exception type

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(HttpRequestValidationException), View = "RequestIsNotValid")]
public class SomeController : Controller {}
```

This will redirect to RequestIsNotValid view, when customErrors mode in web.config is 'on' or 'remote'. Of course, during 'remote', it will be shown only to remote users. If you want to test it during development, set customErrors mode= 'on'

Comment: How do I stope accepting html tags and I want the site to display specific error page rather than displaying the error.

Comment: That is exactle what i answered, don't you read answers? :). Create "RequestIsNotValid" view under Views -> Shared folder and when the request validation error occures, it will display contents of "RequestIsNotValid" view, not the error page details.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to allow HTML for certain properties? That will stop the error from being thrown.

In MVC 3, the AllowHtml attribute does the job.

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/16/AllowHtmlAttributeASPNETMVC3.aspx

Comment: Marting, thanks for the answer, but, I do not want to store or accept any kind of html tags? How do I do that? But the example you wrote gave me is allowing html tags to store in the DB, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, 404 indeed. Rather than posting a link it would be nice to have an actual example posted to counter link rot.